# iOS Shortcut to shuffle-play all songs by a specific artist in my library

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I would like to create a shortcut in iOS 14.4 Shortcuts which shuffle-plays all songs by a particular artist. I can figure out how to specify an album or a playlist, but not songs by a specific artist. Is there anything short of creating a Smart Playlist, to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shuffle By Artist](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/1f640a7087af44cc805202f4be6e6eaf)

Find All Music where Artist contains Ask Each Time (or other equivalent artist condition’. Sort by Random. Play Music.

[image]

Comment: In my case I'll use **Album Artist** contains *<specific artist>*, due to the artist I want having some compilation albums, but otherwise this works great - thanks!